# Report Jenkins on slack channel only for master branch

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, slack-api, slack

How can I set-up the Jenkins build to report the results on slack channel **only for master branch**?

I have the Jenkins build configured (somewhat like https://stackoverflow.com/a/30727490/3609252 ) where `Slack Notifications` > `Project Channel` points to the `#slack_channel`, but this reports all buld reports (including feature branches) into the slack channel which makes it a bit noisy.

Is there a way just to report the build results from the **master** branch of the repo?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can setup 2 Jenkins jobs:

- one only for `master`, with a Slack integration in place (though [`post-receive` hook or webhook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9921495/6309))
- one for any other branches, without any Slack integration.